# Extending properties of a class

Tags: c#, winforms, extension-methods

I'm drawing my custom TabControl. Now I would like to specify the icon via an enum. Usually, when making a custom UserControl, by defining a property with some ComponentModel attributes, you can edit this property in the VS designer. My current code:

```
public class TabPageExtensions
{
    [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(IconType))]
    [Editor(typeof(IconType), typeof(IconType))]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public IconType Icon
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public enum IconType
{
    None, Home, Settings, Bars, Manual, Information, Graph
}
```

But the extended property doesn't show up in the designer. Is there any way to use this enum-type selection in the VS designer with extended properties?

Comment: What is a "Extended property"? AFAIK no such thing.

Comment: I haven't found anything about it too, so I just tried it and it didn't work. But I'm not sure, whether I did a mistake or this doesn't even exist. So I decided to ask stack.

Comment: Create a new control which inherits from the one you're looking at and adds the new property to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit the `Control` you need to extend and add properties, If you don't want to inherit it, you need to Implement [IExtenderprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface which also inherits from `Component` class to extend the properties of objects in design time.

`Tooltip` class implements this interface, that's why you see `ToolTip on ToolTip1` property appears in properties tab even when you don't have such property.

Comment: I tried this and I didn't manage to get it to work. The problem is that the TabControl only accepts System.Windows.Forms.TabPage in the designer. I tried your proposed solution, but this is basically inheriting too. Of course I can edit my designer-file to match this, but I don't think that this is the best solution.

Comment: @mine This doesn't require inheriting the TabControl. It just needs an implementation of  `IExtenderprovider`. It can be any class implementing it. You need a class something like this `class MyExtendedPropertiesProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider
    { }`